# Accidently ran "chown www-data:www-data / -R" as root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, chown

I just ran this a few seconds ago. I managed to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> as soon as I realized what I started doing.

So far the only directory it's started going through is `/bin`.

I'm afraid to do anything else. So far I realized I can't use `su` as my normal user anymore.

Luckily I still have another root terminal open. What do I do?

Comment: Sounds like you got chowned there, buddy.

Comment: Now you understand the importance of backups. Do it regularly.

Comment: At least he didn't chmod from root. That's a full-on disaster. At least rm -rf from root gives you more disk space and prepares you for a full system reinstall, chmod just leaves a real mess that's pretty hard to recover from by anything besides a complete system reinstall. The grass is brown on both sides of the fence, eh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most everything in /bin/ should be owned by root:root, so if you run the following you can fix the ownership on those files:

```
chown root:root -R /bin/
```

You may also want to make sure the setuid bit is properly set on /bin/su, which you can fix with the following:

```
chmod 4755 /bin/su
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, it's especially important to do the same with sudo. I don't think that a root password is even set by default?

By the way, I'd really recommend actually using sudo instead of root shells. The half-second it takes to type sudo normally stops mistakes like that in the tracks. Just working in a root shell is easier to miss...

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/362468/ is a "ls -l /bin" from my Ubuntu 9.10 desktop. While I might not have exactly the same files installed as you, it should at least give you a good hint on which files need special permissions.

Comment: @Bernd:  Although I don't do that much admin work, I have noticed that I sudo fewer dumb things than I do as root.  I may never use a root password ever again.  (And, no, there is no default root password on Ubuntu, and I don't think there is one on MacOSX.)

Comment: @David: There definitely is no default root password on OS X, and setting one is mostly a mistake, IMO. There's almost always another, better way. The problem is that Macs are not too secure to begin with; I expect to see a lot of 'fun' once they have a larger install base to make RKs, Virii, Botnet clients &c profitable.

Answer (score 36):

## Redhat user:

```
chown 0:0 /bin/rpm && rpm -qa | xargs rpm --setugids
```

## Debian/Ubuntu user:

```
chown 0:0 /bin/*  /usr/bin/*
chown daemon:daemon /usr/bin/at
chown 0:utmp /usr/bin/screen
chmod 02755 /usr/bin/screen
chmod u+s /bin/fusermount /bin/mount /bin/su /bin/mount
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/passwd
screen
```

While screen is running do this at least twice:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ if ($2 == "install") print $1}' \
    | xargs apt-get install --reinstall --
```

Pay ***very*** close attention to the output because if it complains about something having the wrong permissions, you should fix it on another screen window.

#### Crash course in screen:

```
Control+A     - command key
Control+A a   - emit a control+A
Control+A n   - next "screen"
Control+A c   - create "screen"
```

## Solaris user:

You're fucked.

```
pkgchk -R / -f -a
```

will reset all the permissions, but setuid-ness will still be broken. Use a backup, or another solaris machine to look for setuid/setgid scripts and files and fix them up manually.

## THE IMPORTANT THING ABOUT BACKUPS

Is that you can recover them, not that you take them.

Other people have given you advice to take backups, but I want to add that you should be testing them. If you're using a unixish system, there is **no reason whatsoever** that you can't dump the files onto another machine periodically and make sure everything works.

Comment: FreeBSD User: would never make this kind of mistake ;)

Comment: @einstiien Yep, FreeBSD users go straight to the `rm -rf` stage.

Comment: @grawity: lol, good one.

Comment: Poor Solaris users :(

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the set-uid flags on any affected binaries may have been removed, too; this is a security feature of chown.  Check with some other system which binaries have the set-uid or set-gid flags and be sure to set them on your binaries as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to explain the details of using RPM to reset file permissions, but I've found a site with a lot [more information](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html). It does also mention that Ubuntu/Debian (so .debs in general) don't support it.

But in general the option your looking for would be along the lines:

```
rpm --setugids {packagename}
```

Comment: This is on an ubuntu system, as indicated by the tags. This means that dpkg and .DEBs are used instead of rpm and .RPMs

Answer (score 2):

If this was a debian system, I'd aptitude reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a working backup? when yes, restore your bin folder.

otherwise, look at an other box where you installed the same version of ubuntu and `chown` to what you find on the working installation.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
find all www-data in /bin directory

```
# find /bin -user www-data
```

then change www-data back to the original user

```
# find /bin -user www-data -exec chown ORiginalUser {} \;

# then change www-data back to oringal group
# find /bin -group www-data -exec chgrp originaluser {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the great responses, everything seems to be fixed now.

/bin/su worked once chmod'd to 4755 (not sure why chown changed the suid bit)

i didnt notice but it also started working through the /home directory but that was an easy enough fix (just set user:group to the user for each dir)