# Chown results in not being able log in VestaCP

Tags: linux, chown

so I needed to chown a folder and I accidently wrote

> chown -R admin:admin /

And that chmowned all files for ~5sec then came up an error that it can not chown something and I stopped.

After I noticed I can not login in VestaCP, I changed password for VestaCP, but still could not log in.

So I checked the pass with somekind of Vestatool + standard login and it worked, so I understood this issue is because of the chmod - VestaCP cant' probably create a session file or something.
Where should I look to set correct permissions? I checked most folders abd can not find any fault with them, comparing to my other server.
Everything else seems working, also did a restart - booted up and running.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/105957/accidently-ran-chown-www-datawww-data-r-as-root?rq=1

Comment: that didnt help

Answer (score 1):

After stopping to look for chmod errors, since that didn't help, I started digging into VestaCP forums and soon came up with

> yum reinstall sudo

that fixed my issue!